# Link an user to his profile page

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

How do I link the logged in user to his profile page?

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}

<a href= "{% url 'blog:profile' userProfile.user %}">Profile</a>
```

Here are the involved parts:

views.py

```
@login_required
def profile(request, profile_id):
    if profile_id == "0":
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            userProfile = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=profile_id)
    else:
        userProfile = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=profile_id)

    return render_to_response('blog/profile.html', {'userProfile':userProfile}, RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<profile_id>\d+)/$', views.profile),
```

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank = True, default=('keine Angabe'), null=True)
    image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.user.username
```

Comment: Any specific problem/error you're facing?

Comment: Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: 
Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: could be there a problem with settings.py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you template you are trying to use `url` tag with named urls even though you haven't passed `name` keyword argument to `url` function in your `urlpatterns`.

In your urls function pass `name` argument, like this:

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<profile_id>\d+)/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
```

**make sure you namespaced the app as 'blog' in your root url conf.**

In your template to access current user's profile id by request context's user object. Like this:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}

    <a href= "{% url 'blog:profile' user.userprofile.id %}">Profile</a>
```